# Where do allies go when they don't have any colonies?

Tags: cosmic-encounter

I was playing Cosmic Encounter as the Masochist, and I was invited as an ally on the offsensive side. The defense played a negotiate card, so the allies were supposed to go back to their colonies, but I had played my last 3 tokens, so I didn't have any colonies.

Where should my ships go?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, good question. Putting your very last token(s) into battle is a risky thing. I think they should go to the warp. You give up a base when you remove your last token from it -- that shouldn't change if they're your very last. And having all your tokens in the warp doesn't remove you from the game or prevent you from capturing a new base on your next turn.

Answer (score 1):

The Warp is correct. Any time you are supposed to put ships on colonies but don't have any colonies, your ships go to the warp ... with one exception:

If you are retrieving a ship from the warp during your own Regroup phase and have no colony to put it on, you instead put it on the hyperspace gate and use it in your encounter.

However, I do have to ask... when you say the *defense* played a negotiate card, did you mean to say *both sides* revealed negotiates? Because otherwise, you would not have been required to return your ships to colonies in the first place.